# Number inside blue box below up votes on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bounty

[image: Stack Overflow upvote icons]

In the answer to [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/7586), under the total number of upvotes, what does the number inside the blue box represent?

Comment: You can hover over it: "This answer received a **bounty** worths <...> by <...>".

Answer (score 11):

Unless I am mistaken, that is pretty simple: that blue'ish number represents the total amount of [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) that was awarded to an answer.

Bounties are a way to attract attention to questions, and can then be awarded to an answer, resulting in the person giving the answer having their reputation boosted by that number. In your case, the answer has 1436 individual upvotes so far, and the author received +100 reputation at some point by bounty.

Comment: It may also have been two bounties worth 50 reputation (although a single bounty seems more likely in this case). In short, I'd like to add that the box shows the *total* value, it may represent more than one bounty.

Comment: Makes sense, updated it accordingly.